# redondear a dos decimales

Tags: php

estoy realizando una consulta en laravel para que me traiga una sumatoria de acuerdo al campo que estoy llamando, mi problema es que hago una conversion para poder sacar el promedio y necesito que me redondee a dos decimales, ya utilize la funcion `round` para que me redonde a dos decimales pero no me lo esta redondeando, puede que yo lo estoy implementando mal o no se como funciona, les dejare el codigo de laravel para que me colaboren

```
$collection = Precebo::join('granjas','granjas.id','=','formulario_precebo.granja_id')
            ->select('granja_id','granjas.nombre_granja','año_destete',DB::raw('sum(numero_inicial) as total'))
            ->whereIn('año_destete',$request->desde)
            ->groupBy('granjas.nombre_granja','año_destete')->get(); 

            $arrayT = [];
            foreach ($collection as $value) {
                $arrayT[]=[$value->granja_id,$value->nombre_granja,$value->total,$value->año_destete];
            }

            $granjas = $request->array;
            $annios = $request->desde;

            $an = $request->annos;

            $categories = array();

            foreach ($annios as $years) {
                foreach ($an as $y) {
                    if ($years == $y) {
                        $categories[] = $y;
                    }
                }
            }

            $array = array();
            $promedios = array();

            foreach ($granjas as $granja) {
                $values = array();
                foreach ($annios as $year) {
                    $anoencontrado = 0;
                    foreach ($arrayT as $data) {
                        if ($granja == $data[0]) {
                            $value = $data[3] ? $data[2] : 0;
                            if ($data[3] == $year) {
                                $values[] = $value;
                                $anoencontrado = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($anoencontrado === 0) {
                        $values[] = 0;
                    }
                }
                foreach ($arrayT as $data) {
                    if ($granja == $data[0]) {
                        $array[]=array(
                            'name' => $data[1],
                            'data' => $values
                        );
                        $suma = 0;
                        foreach ($values as $value) {
                            $suma += $value;
                        }
                        $promedios[]= array(
                            'name'=> $data[1],
                            'value'=>(count($values) !== 0)? $suma / count($values) : 0
                        );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $suma = 0;
            $suma_granjas = 0;
            foreach ($array as $arra) {
                $suma_granjas++;
            }
            foreach ($promedios as $promedio) {
                $suma += $promedio['value'];
            }
            $promedioGeneral = ($suma_granjas !== 0) ? $suma / $suma_granjas : 0;
            round($promedioGeneral);

            return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$array,'categories'=>$categories,'general'=>$promedioGeneral,'granjas'=>$suma_granjas],200);
```

Comment: Hola, no se si estas utilizando javascrip o jquery en tu proyecto pero si es así podrías utilizar la función toFixed(2) para redondear los decimales .

Answer (score 5):

Te falta asignar el valor a algo

```
$promedioGeneral = round($promedioGeneral,2);
```

Alternativamente y si necesitas completar con 0 a la derecha podes usar `sprintf`

```
<?php
$dinero1 = 68.75;
$dinero2 = 54.351234123;
$dinero = $dinero1 + $dinero2;
echo $dinero.PHP_EOL;
$formateado = sprintf("%01.2f", $dinero);
echo $formateado;
```

*tomado de la página de ejemplos del manual de PHP

http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda con el round, no sabia que me faltaba solo eso para que me funcionanara

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con esto

```
round($promedioGeneral, 2);
```

El 2 es para el número de dígitos desde el punto decimal